# Change platform for kubernetes when pulling image

Tags: docker, kubernetes, apple-m1

I am using an Apple M1, writing a Kubernetes YAML file to pull and deploy the image `confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.2.4` the problem is, I cannot pull the image due to the difference in CPU architecture

```
Failed to pull image "confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.2.4": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = no matching manifest for linux/arm64/v8 in the manifest list entries
```

When using docker-compose, I can just specify the tag `platform: linux/x86_64` and everything goes as normal, but I'm not sure how to do this for K8S, I have tried to set the environment variable `DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM` as well but it's not working either.

I'm using Docker-Desktop's built in Kubernetes

Comment: Which kubernetes type of cluster are you deploying to? (Minkube,kind, deployed with kubeadm?)

Comment: @bguess I do not recall installing minukube or anything like that, I'm using the Kubernetes cluster that is included in the Docker-Desktop UI (The "Enable Kubernetes" checkbox)

Comment: I'm having the same kind of thing; using Minikube on M1 processor.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72325482/minikube-to-deploy-linux-amd64-images-on-m1-hardware

Answer (score 0):

As I know there is no option for Pods/Deployments to define an architecture.
I assume, that Kubernetes will automatically pull the correct image if you point to a Container image context. When you have only single images without an index then you have to work with nodeSelectors or something else and to pin the CPU architecture over the image tag (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#multi-architecture-images-with-image-indexes).

To your given image in your question:
In this case, I think, is the issue that `confluentinc/cp-zookeeper` has a ARM64 image in Docker Hub but no ARM64/v8 image.
Now I don't know the internals of Docker on M1. But I am a bit surprised that x86_64 even work on an ARM CPU.

Answer (score -3):

just can only use image digest, like `<image-name>@<digest>`

```
  db:
    image: mysql@sha256:358b0482ced8103a8691c781e1cb6cd6b5a0b463a6dc0924a7ef357513ecc7a3
    container_name: mysql
```

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#image-pull-policy

> To make sure the Pod always uses the same version of a container image, you can specify the image's digest; replace : with @ (for example, image@sha256:45b23dee08af5e43a7fea6c4cf9c25ccf269ee113168c19722f87876677c5cb2).

Comment: Please add all details in english