# Minikube to deploy linux/amd64 images on M1 hardware

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube, apple-m1

I know it's possible to run locally on Apple's M1 processor an amd64 image by using the `--platform linux/amd64` flag on `docker run`.

But how do I deploy that same image on a local Minikube cluster, running on this same M1 hardware?

Output when trying is:

```
Failed to pull image "registry/image:tag": 
rpc error: code = Unknown desc = no matching manifest for linux/arm64/v8 in the manifest list entries
```

How do I tell Minikube to cause the same effect as `--platform linux/amd64` flag on its deployment?

Comment: Do you found a solution ? I have the same issue.

Comment: can you add the whole command/yaml that you use to run the image?

Comment: Just curious, is that still an issue that you can reproduce, because I couldn't --> https://yelling.cloud/posts/docker_and_minikube/

Comment: @RickRackow I followed your blog and also could not reproduce it with your examples. But can you try and run `kubectl run timescale --image timescale/timescaledb-ha:pg15.3-ts2.10.3-all`? This is single arch amd64 and it does fail for me like for OP.

Comment: Nevermind. Seems to be a timescale specific problem, since they are in the middle of supporting multi-arch images...

Answer (score 2):

Not sure with Docker Desktop, but if you use Colima, you can select the arch for the lima VM.

Once you have a docker engine running in a VM with arch x86_64 on the M1, it will pull amd64 images.

use `colima start --arch x86_64` on startup to use that arch.

You can then run MiniKube on Colima, or just use the Colima built-in kubernetes cluster.

Note: You may need to use the --runtime containerd to make this work. I have had issues with using the default runtime (docker)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue. My solution was to:

1. Pull the image locally as you described with `docker pull registry/image:tag --platform linux/amd64`.
2. Set your containers spec's `imagePullPolicy` to `Never`, which makes it get the image locally rather than pulling it from the registry:

```yaml
spec:
  containers:
  - name: container-name
    image: registry/image:tag
    imagePullPolicy: Never  # or IfNotPresent
```

Both `kind` and `minikube` set the `imagePullPolicy` to `Always` whenever an image with the `latest` tag is used, so manually setting it to `Never` forces the node to use your already downloaded image.